# Seleccionar colores para gráfica en función de la cantidad de datos

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualización-de-datos

estoy trabajando con un dataframe de estadísticas de futbol con la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De este DF trabajo individualmente cada jugador, necesito hacer una gráfica de pastel con las últimas 4 columnas. Para hacerlo estoy usando este código:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import colors

# jugador es arbitrario
df_j=df[df['player_name']==jugador].reset_index(drop=True)
columnas=['right_foot','left_foot','headers','others']
lables=['Derecha','Izquierda','Cabeza','Otros']
datos=[[],[]]
for i,lable in zip(columnas,lables):
    if df_j[i][0]>0:
        datos[0].append(df_j[i][0])
        datos[1].append(lable)
normdata=colors.Normalize(min(datos[0]),max(datos[0]))
colormap = cm.get_cmap("Set3")
colores =colormap(normdata(datos[0]))

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.pie(datos[0],labels=datos[1], colors=colores, autopct="%0.2f %%",pctdistance=0.9,wedgeprops={'linewidth': 2.5, 'edgecolor': 'white'})
print(colores)
plt.show()
```

Al realizar la gráfica de Sané por ejemplo no tengo problemas ya que hay diferentes colores. Pero si uso los valores de De Bruyne al tener la misma cantidad el gráfico no queda bien.

En su opinion:

1. Para solucionar mi problema seria mejor utilizar un diccionario de colores?

   - En caso que si, como lo podría implementar?
2. Existe alguna forma mas 'profesional' o avanzada para seleccionar los colores?
3. Es buena idea continuar con la propuesta que tengo para graficar o existe alguna manera mejor, tomando en cuenta que voy a agregar una gráfica anidada?
   Estoy balándome en este [tutorial](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-make-a-beautiful-donut-chart-and-nested-donut-chart-in-matplotlib-92040c8bbeea)?

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si únicamente necesitas la gráfica de pastel de las últimas columnas y tu `dataframe` original ya tiene las columnas puedes hacerlo de una forma muy sencilla

Yo evitaría seleccionar colores manualmente ya que en algún momento podría haber un escenario como el que tienes ahora donde los colores sean iguales

Con el siguiente `dataframe` de ejemplo (**Nota:** cuando hagas una pregunta siempre agrega los datos como texto para que los podamos copiar y pegar, como están en imagen solo puse 2 filas)

```
    player_name goals   right_foot  left_foot   headers others
0   Sané        6.0     1.0         5.0         0.0     0.0
1   De Bruyne   2.0     1.0         0.0         1.0     0.0
```

Lo único que hay que hacer es, seleccionar la fila y las columnas que hay que graficar y utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df.loc[0,'right_foot':].plot.pie(legend=True)
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica de muestra]

Ahora, si cada fila tiene un nombre de jugador diferente, lo puedes hacer más entendible al primero hacer `player_name` los índices y luego graficas utilizando el nombre del jugador

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col='player_name')
df.loc['De Bruyne','right_foot':].plot.pie(legend=True)
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica con nombre de jugador como índice]

Te recomiendo revisar la documentación de `plot.pie` para saber que argumentos puedes pasar para poner por ejemplo título, seleccionar colores, posicionar la leyenda, etc, pero esa sería la forma más rápida y sencilla de hacer tus gráficas de pastel.

**Edición:** Pero si en verdad quieres asignar los colores de forma manual sin que se repitan, lo que podrías hacer es generar gradientes de tus colores, por ejemplo, al tomar el `colormap` "Reds" podemos generar colores con gradiente utilizando `linspace()` de `numpy`

```
cmap = plt.cm.Reds
colors = [*cmap(np.linspace(.6, .1, 4))]
```

Otra opción sería multiplicandolo por el número de columna y con eso formar un gradiente pero en general yo evitaría asignar colores de forma manual

**Edición 2:** Como en tu caso utilizas `colors.Normalize` lo que ocaciona es que al tener valores iguales el resultado genera ceros, podrías sumarles algun valor para que el color se vea diferente

```
normdata=colors.Normalize(min(datos[0]),max(datos[0]))
colormap = cm.get_cmap("Set3")
colores = colormap(normdata(datos[0])+[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])
```